# session[:user_id] returning nil even if user signed in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, devise, omniauth

**omniauth_callbacks_controller**

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

def facebook

 @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

 if @user.persisted?
  sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
  set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
 else
  session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
  redirect_to new_user_registration_url
  end
 end
end
```

**session_controller**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

 def create
  user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
  #sign_in(:user, user)
  session[:user_id] = user.id 
  redirect_to root_url
 end

 def destroy
  session[:user_id] = nil
  redirect_to root_url
 end
end
```

**application_controller**

```
 class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
    # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
       protect_from_forgery with: :exception
    private
    helper_method :current_user
    def current_user
         @current_user = User.find(session[:user_id])  
    end

  end
```

**user.rb**

```
   class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
      # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
      devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,:omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]
      belongs_to :restaurant, foreign_key: 'restaurant_id'
      has_many :orders
      def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
        user.provider = auth.provider
        user.uid = auth.uid
        user.name = auth.info.name
        user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
        user.email = auth.info.email
        user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
        user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)

      end
  end
end
```

**visitor_controller**

```
 class VisitorsController < ApplicationController

   def index
     @user = current_user

   end
 end
```

This is the root page controller of my app.
I am creating a restaurant ordering app, but the problem is all orders are being displayed to all user.

So i need to make each order user specific.
But I am not being able to access 'user.id'  from any of my controller.

Please help.
Not being able to find the problem. 
Thank you.

Comment: you are using devise ? then no need to save user_id in session current_user will always available on each controller

Comment: you are not able to find current_user.id on controllers ???

Comment: yep.

if i remove my session_controller.
I'l be able to retrieve current_user?

Comment: when you are login with facebook you are able to see flash messgae?? if not then it seems to me related to authencitytoken issue check this:https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2432

Comment: It does show flash messages.
FB auth is working totally fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an application where you intend to use Devise and OmniAuth together you do not need to create a custom `SessionsController`.

You would simply need [customize to the login page](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-views) with a link:

```
<%= link_to "/auth/facebook", "Sign in with Facebook" %>
```

Note that the same callback URL will be used for both new and returning users!

`sign_in_and_redirect`in your Users::OmniauthCallbacksController  in will handle serialing the user in the session with the help of Warden and you can sign out user by the normal Devise controller.

---

### Edit

The biggest problem with you seem to have is understanding how OmniAuth and Devise work together.

Devise provides a normal user / password signup and all the functionality needed for sessions.

OmniAuth provides abstraction for dealing with different OAuth providers and dealing with details of OAuth.

All your callbacks controller need to do is call Devises `sign_in_and_redirect` method and it will take care of serializing the user in the session through Warden.

Comment: thank you for helping, but would it help me if i want normal signups and facebook authorizations both in my application?

what if a user does not have a facebook account?

and also,( session[:user_id]) is defined in session_controller.

Will it still get defined in onmiauth controller?
Because my main concern is retrieving the user id.

Comment: I tried making it work by deleting my sessions_controller.
And also by adding a link_to you specified.

Facebook auth worked perfectly.
Restarted the server.
But still, current_user is nil.

Comment: Also, the current_user function shows an error, 

shows an error , _couldn't find user with 'id'=_

Comment: "what if a user does not have a facebook account?" - Then they should be authenticated by the normal `Devise::SessionsController`. You should start with a normal working Devise user/password setup and then ALL you need to add is a controller to handle the Oauth callbacks, and a route to that controller, plus links on your sign up / sign in views.

Comment: Get rid of your current_user method - the sessions controller and all the other half broken junk - you don't need to override anything in devise besides the views to add OmniAuth.

Comment: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Controllers/Helpers#sign_in_and_redirect-instance_method